# How to get Metadata information in Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, metadata

I want to get the metadata information in Hbase. My basic purpose is to -

> 1.get the information about tables like how many tables and name of tables.
>
> 2.get the columnfamilies name in each table.
>
> 3.get the columns names and their data types in each columnfamily.
>
> Is there any tool or command by using which we can get the above
>   information ??

Comment: I know the question is bit old to make more relevant  I added my answer. pls check

Answer (score 3):

**Through the API :**

1. Use **[getTableNames()](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#getTableNames%28%29)** provided by **HBaseAdmin** class. It returns an array of strings containing names of all userspace tables.
2. Use **[getMap()](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getMap%28%29)** provided by the class **Result**. It returns a map of families to all versions of its qualifiers and values. You can extract the desired info from it.
3. Can be achieved through getMap(). And as far as datatype is concerned, everything in HBase is an **array of bytes**.

**Through shell :**

There is no OOTB feature which allows this, but you could use HBase commands in conjunction with **awk** to achieve that quickly :

**For example :**

> **List table names and the count :** echo "scan 'demo'" | bin/hbase shell
>   | awk -F" " '{print$1}'
>
> **Get all the CFs :** echo "scan 'test1'" | bin/hbase shell | awk -F"="
>   '{print$2}' | awk -F":" '{print $1}'
>
> **Get all the columns :** echo "scan 'demo'" | bin/hbase shell | awk -F"=" '{print$2}' | awk -F"," '{print$1}' | awk -F":" '{print$2}'

HTH

Comment: Tarik ,THANX for the response .I am getting the list of tables and column families .But I am still not able to get column names .can you send me a working example ??

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use `HbaseAdmin` class which is there in  Hbase client API

Below is the example program to get All tables and columns similary you can go ahead and get other information as well! Also, have a look at [HTableDescriptor.html](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HTableDescriptor.html)

```
package mytest;
import com.usertest.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class ListHbaseTablesAndColumns {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HbaseMetaData hbaseMetaData  =new HbaseMetaData();
            for(String hbaseTable:hbaseMetaData  .getTableNames(".*yourtables.*")){
                    for (String column : hbaseMetaData  .getColumns(hbaseTable, 10000)) {
                        System.out.println(hbaseTable + "," + column);
                    }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Use below class to Get HbaseMetaData..

```
package com.usertest;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.PageFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HbaseMetaData {
    private HBaseAdmin hBaseAdmin;
    private Configuration hBaseConfiguration;

    public HbaseMetaData () throws IOException {
        this.hBaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        this.hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(hBaseConfiguration);
    }
/** get all Table names **/
    public List<String> getTableNames(String regex) throws IOException {
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
        List<String> tableList = new ArrayList<String>();
        TableName[] tableNames=hBaseAdmin.listTableNames();
        for (TableName tableName:tableNames){
            if(pattern.matcher(tableName.toString()).find()){
                tableList.add(tableName.toString());
            }
        }
        return tableList;
    }
/** Get all columns **/
    public Set<String> getColumns(String hbaseTable) throws IOException {
        return getColumns(hbaseTable, 10000);
    }
/** get all columns from the table **/
    public Set<String> getColumns(String hbaseTable, int limitScan) throws IOException {
        Set<String> columnList = new TreeSet<String>();
        HTable hTable=new HTable(hBaseConfiguration, hbaseTable);
        Scan scan=new Scan();
        scan.setFilter(new PageFilter(limitScan));
        ResultScanner results = hTable.getScanner(scan);
        for(Result result:results){
            for(KeyValue keyValue:result.list()){
                columnList.add(
                        new String(keyValue.getFamily()) + ":" +
                                new String(keyValue.getQualifier())
                );
            }
        }
        return columnList;
    }
}
```